# Omitt some xticklabels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

I am currently reading some data from a CSV-file together with the xticklabels as one column from that file:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data/test1_d4.csv}\dataTestOneFour
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    minor y tick num = 3,
    ylabel={$\mu(\Phi)$},
    flexible xticklabels from table={data/test1_d4.csv}{N}{col sep=comma},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}, 
    xtick=data
    ]
    \addplot[gray,thick,mark=x] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=wB]{\dataTestOneFour};
    \addplot[light-gray,thick,mark=x] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=mu]{\dataTestOneFour};
    \addplot[lighter-gray,thick,mark=x] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=uB]{\dataTestOneFour};
    \legend{data 1, data 2, data 3};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{\emph{$d = 4$ }}\label{fig:test1_d4}
\end{figure}
```

But as soon as I produce a lot of data the xticklabels overlap and I would be nice if I could omitt some of them automatically. But I never found how one can specify the total number of xticks. Is this possible?

[image: this is what I got so far]

Comment: Please expand your code sniped to workable example with add `\documentclass`, related packages as well table with your data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know an automatic method to proceed this, i just modified the `xticklabels' option: here is the example:(manual method)
[image]

```
    \documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        scaled ticks=true,
        ]
                \addplot[green, mark=o] table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAPbjh2.dat};\label{plotsplot22};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        scaled ticks=true,
        xticklabels={,0,,40,,80,,120}       
        ]
                \addplot[green, mark=o] table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAPbjh2.dat};\label{plotsplot22}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know of this method and unfortunately not what I wanted because I don't want to care about data size. In my oppinion this should be handled by the drawing framework -- not the user.